# Cloning an n-ary tree in C

Tags: c, pointers, tree

My structure maintains a parent, child and sibling pointers along with other data variables.

```
struct semNode {
    struct semNode *child;
    struct semNode *parent;
    struct semNode *sibling;
    int data;
    int tag;
};
```

If I have to clone an exact tree of the same data type, how do I go about it in a recursive or an iterative manner.

I planned to take a recursive approach where I traverse the tree in an in order fashion and then add to the pointers but I'm not sure if that approach will work. Please help me out.

Comment: When you work with trees is always better using recursive solutions.

Comment: @lesheenSaxena: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the tree with a simple recursive function:

```
struct semNode {
    struct semNode *child;
    struct semNode *parent;
    struct semNode *sibling;
    int data;
    int tag;
};

void free_semNode(struct semNode *node) {
    if (node) {
        free_semNode(node->sibling);
        free_semNode(node->child);
        free(node);
    }
}

struct semNode *clone_semNode(struct semNode *node, struct semNode *parent) {
    struct semNode *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->data = node->data;
        new_node->tag = node->tag;
        new_node->parent = parent;
        new_node->child = NULL;
        new_node->sibling = NULL;
        if (node->child) {
            new_node->child = clone_semNode(node->child, new_node);
            if (new_node->child == NULL) {
                free_semNode(new_node);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        if (node->sibling) {
            new_node->sibling = clone_semNode(node->sibling, parent);
            if (new_node->sibling == NULL) {
                free_semNode(new_node);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

The whole tree can be cloned with `clone_semNode(tree, NULL);` and a subtree can be cloned with `clone_semNode(node, node->parent);` but both the original subtree and the cloned subtree will point to the same parent, which may cause difficulties for proper memory management.